# Como sugerir sinônimo de tags?

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

Hoje eu ia fazer uma pergunta com a tag 'semântica', mas imaginei que alguém já tivesse feito uma pergunta com dúvidas semânticas.
Foi então que buscando perguntas análogas vi que usa-se a tag 'significado'.

Dito isso, como posso sugerir um sinônimo para uma tag?

Comment: Achas que *semântica* seria sinônimo de *significado*?

Comment: @tchrist Sim, para você não?

Comment: Para mim, a *semântica* pode trazer um sentido mais amplo que o *significado*, mas talvez tenhas razão que os dois estão perto o suficiente para valer a pena criar sinônimos. Nós podemos fazê-lo se a comunidade quiser. Os artigos de Wikipédia sobre as duas palavras são bastante curtos em português, pelo menos em comparação com os artigos em inglês. EN: [Semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics), [Meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meaning_(linguistics)). De lá podes escolher as versões em português para ver o que eu quero dizer.

Comment: [Página do Help Centre relevante](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms).